# Access variables from anonymous JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, variables

Is it possible to access variables within an anonymous function outside of said function?

I may be using the wrong terminology.

Using the below pseudo code, would it be possible to access var1 in another script loaded on the same page?

```
function(i,e){
    var var1;
    NewFunc.init = function(){
         var1 = 5; 
    };
}
```

Comment: Side Note: You have syntax errors in that code which makes it a bit tricky to be sure of your structure. The question text is probably clear enough, but it's worth fixing the code...

Comment: *"I may be using the wrong terminology."* Nope, that's just about perfect terminology.

Comment: Ah thanks, just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to access variables within an anonymous function outside of said function?

No, and in fact this is one of the things we use functions for: Hiding things. :-) More below about why that's not just a quirk of syntax.

Variables within a function are entirely private to that function and other functions created *within* it (which "close over" the variables in scope where they're created). For instance:

```js
function foo() {
  var answer = 42;

  function bar() {
    var question = "Life, the Universe, and Everything";
    console.log(question, answer); // Works fine
  }
  console.log(question, answer);   // Fails with a ReferenceError because
                                   // `question` is out of scope
}
foo();
```

`bar` can access `foo`'s `answer` variable because `bar` is created within `foo`. But `foo` cannot access `bar`'s `question` variable because `foo` *isn't* created within `bar`.

This means it's possible to create functions that can access and modify a private variable:

```js
// This is ES5 and earlier style; in ES2015+, it could be a bit more concise
function foo() {
  var answer = 42;
  return {
    getAnswer: function() {
      return answer;
    },
    setAnswer: function(value) {
      answer = value;
    }
  };
}
var o = foo();
console.log(o.getAnswer()); // 42
o.setAnswer(67);
console.log(o.getAnswer()); // 67
```

Note that if we tried to replace

```
console.log(o.getAnswer()); // 42
```

with

```
console.log(answer);
```

there are two good reasons that fails:

1. The variable is out of scope
2. If somehow it were *in* scope, which `answer` should it refer to? We can call `foo` more than once, and each call creates a new `answer` variable, so...

---

Side note: It makes no difference whether the function is named or anonymous, or whether it's a normal function or one of ES2015's new "arrow" functions.

Comment: Was afraid that would be the case - thanks for your quick response!

Comment: @eggman: FWIW, added a bit more information which may help with what you're trying to fix (your "was afraid that would be the case" suggests to me you're trying to fix something :-) ).

Comment: Crowder: Yes was looking for a solution will try a different approach now. Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation, it has certainly helped to understand the scope of variables within functions.